# ansible not moving to the next step after completetion

Tags: linux, ansible

I have a ansible `shell` task that executes a sh script thats this:

```
#/bin/bash

echo Which version will you be using
read VERSION
export VERSION=$VERSION

sh deployvcenter.v1.sh

sh deployf5.v1.sh

sh deployadmin.sh
```

the ansible task looks like this:

```
- name: Run build scripts
  shell:
    cmd: echo "beta-1" | sudo sh /home/admin/buildscripts/deployall.sh >> /tmp/build.log
    chdir: /home/admin/buildscripts
  become: true
  become_method: su
  become_user: root
```

the last part the `deployadmin.sh` is this:

`terraform init && terraform apply -var-file=static-ip.tfvars -auto-approve -input=false`

terraform does complete as the `/tmp/build.log` has this at the end:

```
vsphere_virtual_machine.vm: Still creating... (1m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.vm: Creation complete after 1m17s (ID: 4226c091-bb3a-4d3a-d2af-c31933425991)

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

ip_address = ip addy
```

but ansible just sits at that task and doesn't move to the next one.

`TASK [Run build scripts] *******************************************************`

I don't understand why its not moving to the next one or erroring out?

UPDATE:

I let this run and after about an hr or so I got this:

```
TASK [Run build scripts] *******************************************************

fatal: [ip]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to ip closed.\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

thats strange because I'm ssh'd into the machine on a separate terminal and did it again it still there...the task did complete successfully so I'm not quite sure what its trying to do...

Comment: That suggests that your shell scripts are not actually exiting. Have you used `ps` to see if the scripts (or the commands they are calling) are in fact still running? You're packing a lot into your shell scripts that might better be separate ansible tasks (and doing to so might make things easier to diagnose).

Comment: It would be _much_ more in line with best practices to not call nested shell scripts from an ansible play. The shell/command modules really should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. Why not use the ansible terraform module directly?

Comment: agree...but these a pre-created and there's a lot in there that aren't easy to move into ansible right now....when I run them manually, they run and exited...I looked at `ps` but nothing in there ...I did make an update though to the question cause I let it run longer and it said the server wasn't reachable then but it still is

Comment: Separately, it's also very, very bizarre to invoke `sudo` in a task that is `become: true`

Comment: yep....just trying everything I can to get this to run unfortunately

Comment: You might try increasing the timeouts in ansible.cfg. It might also be worth looking into having this task run asyncrounously and polling for its completion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post my own answer here as a workaround as after hours and hours I just couldn't figure out what it wouldn't move to the next step.

Definitely the least efficient way to do this (not to mention other issues with this), but hopefully this gives anyone else who runs into something similar an idea of how to get around it if they're in a similar situation.

I ended up running the tast with `nohup` like this:

```
   - name: Run build scripts
      shell: cd /home/admin/buildscripts; nohup sh deployall.sh > /tmp/build.log 2>&1 &
      become: true
      become_method: su
      become_user: root
```

The task that runs the shell command completes and the process does exit properly but not sure why ansible doesn't pick it up.

I then added another task to see if the vcenter server and other servers come up like this:

```
- name: Wait for Vcenter to come alive
  uri:
    url: "https://vcenter/vsphere-client/?csp"
    status_code: 200
    validate_certs: False
  register: result
  until: result.status == 200
  retries: 240
  delay: 30
  tags:
    - debug

- name: Wait for F5 to come alive and get token
  uri:
    url: https://{{ f5_addr }}/mgmt/shared/authn/login
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    body:
      username: '{{ f5_user }}'
      password: '{{ f5_pass }}'
      needsToken: true
    return_content: yes
    validate_certs: no
  register: token
  until: token.status == 200
  retries: 240
  delay: 30
  tags:
    - f5license

- name: Waits ws to come up
  wait_for:
    host: '{{ admin_ip }}'
    port: 22
```